# Java JTable update row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am creating a JTable like this:

```java
           String[] colName = new String[] {
               "ID#", "Country", "Name", "Page titel", "Page URL", "Time"
           };
           Object[][] products = new Object[][] {
               {
                   "123", "USA", "Bill", "Start", "http://www.url.com", "00:04:23"
               },

               {
                   "55", "USA", "Bill", "Start", "http://www.url.com", "00:04:23"
               }

           };

           dtm = new DefaultTableModel(products, colName);
           table = new JTable(dtm);
```

How could i update the row by ID? i want to update the whole row where the ID equals 55.

Edit: I know how to detele by row ID but how do i actually update the cells?

```java
  public void removeVisitorFromTable(String visitorID) {
    int row = -1; //index of row or -1 if not found

    //search for the row based on the ID in the first column
    for(int i=0;i<dtm.getRowCount();++i)
        if(dtm.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(visitorID)) {
            row = i;
            break;
        }

    if(row != -1) {
        dtm.removeRow(row);//remove row
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: And what did you try ?

Comment: What did you try? A `for loop` should fit the need.

Comment: Have you looked at the [How to use JTables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire) and the [JTable reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) before asking? If so, what's your problem? Its pretty well explained there.
Mandatory [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) link.

Comment: @DSquare dont understand how to update a row, can u make an simple example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [DefaultTableModel#setValueAt(java.lang.Object, int, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

or

[DefaultTableModel#setDataVector(java.util.Vector, java.util.Vector)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29)

### **Edit:**

Example:

```
private void updateRow(String visitorID, String[] data) {
    if (data.length > 5)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("data[] is to long");
    for (int i = 0; i < dtm.getRowCount(); i++)
        if (dtm.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(visitorID))
            for (int j = 1; j < data.length+1; j++)
                dtm.setValueAt(data[j-1], i, j);
}
```