# How to fire `fireTableDataChanged` properly

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a reasonable simple `JTable` that I want to update every second.

To do this, I found that you are supposed to use `fireTableDataChanged()`, however, after several attempts I still can't get it to work.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Changer extends JFrame {
    int phils = 1;
    int daves = 2;
    int bobs = 3;
    String[] cols = {"Name", "Num"};
    Object[][] data = {{"Phil", phils},
                       {"Dave", daves},
                       {"Bob", bobs}};
    DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);
    JTable table = new JTable(dm);

    public Changer() {
        super("Changer");

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        add(p);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                phils++;
                daves++;
                bobs++;
                data = new Object[][] {{"Phil", phils},
                           {"Dave", daves},
                           {"Bob", bobs}};
                dm.fireTableDataChanged();
                repaint();
                revalidate();
                table.repaint();
                table.revalidate();

                System.out.println(phils + ", " + daves + ", " + bobs);
            }
        });

        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Changer();
    }
}
```

To begin with I just had

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        phils++;
        daves++;
        bobs++;

        dm.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
});
```

As the docs seem to suggest it would work if the values are updated.

Then I tried

```
Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        phils++;
        daves++;
        bobs++;

        data = new Object[][] {{"Phil", phils},
               {"Dave", daves},
               {"Bob", bobs}};
        dm.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
});
```

To see if I had to physically update the variable `data`.

Finally I added all the validates and repaints to see if that would make a difference, and a `System.out.println` just incase I had made a mistake with the timer somehow. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DefaultTableModel` you are using  creates a `Vector` from your `Object` array and uses that as its data :

```
protected static Vector convertToVector(Object[][] anArray) {
        if (anArray == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Vector<Vector> v = new Vector<Vector>(anArray.length);
        for (Object[] o : anArray) {
            v.addElement(convertToVector(o));
        }
        return v;
    }
```

This means that replacing the array (or even modifying its content) **won't** magically reflect any change to the model.

What you can do before calling `dm.fireTableDataChanged()` is either

**Replace the data of the model**

```
dm.setDataVector(data, cols);
```

**Or delete all rows and insert the new ones**

```
while(dm.getRowCount()>0){
       dm.removeRow(0);
}
dm.addRow(new Object[] {"Phil", phils });
dm.addRow(new Object[] {"Dave", daves  });
dm.addRow(new Object[] {"Bob", bobs });
```

**Or search for the row matching the name, then update the row :**

```
updateRow(new Object[] {"Phil", phils });
updateRow(new Object[] {"Dave", daves  });
updateRow(new Object[] {"Bob", bobs });
```

with this `updateRow` method largely inspired from [Java JTable update row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618436/java-jtable-update-row) :

```
private void updateRow( Object[] data) {

        String userName = data[0].toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < dm.getRowCount(); i++)
            if (dm.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(userName))
                for (int j = 1; j < data.length; j++)
                    dm.setValueAt(data[j], i, j);
    }
```